# Overlay a Normal curve to Histogram

Tags: r, statistics

I repeat 50 times a rnorm with n=100, mean=100 and sd=25. Then I plot the histogram of all the sample means, but now I need to overlay a normal curve over the histogram.

```
x <- replicate(50, rnorm(100, 100, 25), simplify = FALSE)
x
sapply(x, mean)
sapply(x, sd)

hist(sapply(x, mean))
```

Do you know ow to overlay a normal curve over the histogram of the means?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we plot the density rather than the frequency histogram by setting `freq=FALSE`, we may overlay a `curve` of a normal distribution with the mean of the means. For the `xlim` of the `curve` we use the `range` of the means.

```
mean.of.means <- mean(sapply(x, mean))
r <- range(sapply(x, mean))

v <- hist(sapply(x, mean), freq=FALSE, xlim=r, ylim=c(0, .5))
curve(dnorm(x, mean=mean.of.means, sd=1), r[1], r[2], add=TRUE, col="red")
```

[image]

Also possible is to draw a sufficient amount of a normal distribution, and overlay the histogram with the `lines` of the `density` distribution.

```
lines(density(rnorm(1e6, mean.of.means, 1)))
```

**Note,** that I have used 500 mean values in my answer, since the comparison with a normal distribution may become meaningless with too few values. However, you can play with the `breaks=` option in the `histogram` function.

#### Data

```
set.seed(42)
x <- replicate(500, rnorm(100, 100, 25), simplify = FALSE)
```

Comment: I noticed the downvote. Is there something wrong with my answer? Please tell me where it might need to be improved.